# Discord.py | Sorting member's

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Code Task: 
When using the command, the bot displays a list of all server participants.

My problem: 
My problem is that my list is issued according to an unknown sorting for me.

How do I want it to look like: 
I want the participants to be sorted by which user logged in to the server. And also, if it is not difficult, then add a number corresponding to their place near their nicknames.

For a more detailed understanding, I have added photos below of how it looks now and how it should look.

Code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import asyncio
import math

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("c:"), intents=discord.Intents.all())

@Bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def members(ctx):
    members = [str(m) for m in ctx.guild.members]
    per_page = 10 
    pages = math.ceil(len(members) / per_page)
    cur_page = 1
    chunk = members[:per_page]
    linebreak = "\n"
    memberCount = str(ctx.guild.member_count)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n", description = f"{linebreak.join(chunk)}")
    embed.set_footer(text = f'Members: {memberCount}')
    message = await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    await message.add_reaction("◀️")
    await message.add_reaction("▶️")
    active = True

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["◀️", "▶️"]

    while active:
        try:
            reaction, user = await Bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)

            if str(reaction.emoji) == "▶️" and cur_page != pages:
                cur_page += 1
                if cur_page != pages:
                    chunk = members[(cur_page-1)*per_page:cur_page*per_page]
                    memberCount = str(ctx.guild.member_count)
                    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n", description = f"{linebreak.join(chunk)}")
                    embed.set_footer(text = f'Members: {memberCount}')
                else:
                    chunk = members[(cur_page-1)*per_page:]
                    memberCount = str(ctx.guild.member_count)
                    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n", description = f"{linebreak.join(chunk)}")
                    embed.set_footer(text = f'Members: {memberCount}')
                await message.edit(embed = embed)
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

            elif str(reaction.emoji) == "◀️" and cur_page > 1:
                cur_page -= 1
                chunk = members[(cur_page-1)*per_page:cur_page*per_page]
                memberCount = str(ctx.guild.member_count)
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n", description = f"{linebreak.join(chunk)}")
                embed.set_footer(text = f'Members: {memberCount}')
                await message.edit(embed=embed) 
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.delete()
            active = False
```

[How should I be on the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q6XO.png)

[How does it show me in the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vhvd.png)

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzeW2.png)

Comment: "I want the participants to be sorted by which user logged in to the server." I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean that it should show all the online users first, and then all the offline users? Within each of those groups, does the order matter?

Comment: No.
Let's take an example:
You are logged in to the server as a member of 14, and you will also be displayed in the list of 14. Online and offline modes have nothing to do with this.
I hope I made myself clear, look at the images.

Comment: No, I don't understand at all from the images. Your image for the actual result only shows page 2 of the results, and I don't understand what the rule is that tells you the correct order in the desired results. The only thing that seems to be clear is that you want some user named "SOPHIST" to appear first instead of not-first, but I have no idea why.

Comment: You said "My problem is that my list is issued according to an unknown sorting for me." and then "I want the participants to be sorted by which user logged in to the server.", so I assume that you mean that right now, the correct amount of users are shown, and all the correct users are shown, but they are in the wrong order. But I can't understand your explanation of the desired order. You say "by which user logged in to the server". But **every** user logged into the server! That's why they're there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both things could be done relatively easy.

1. You can use the `sorted` function and sort the members according to the `joined_at` attribute

```py
members = [str(m) for m in sorted(ctx.guild.members, key=lambda m: m.joined_at)]
```

2. To add the numbers you can use the `enumerate` function.

```py
members = [f"{i}. {m}" for i, m in enumerate(members, start=1)]
```

You can combine everything into one line

```py
members = [f"{i}. {m}" for i, m in enumerate(sorted(ctx.guild.members, key=lambda m: m.joined_at), start=1)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.